# Counting elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long (approx. 4000 rows) list whose elements are in the form as follows:

```
{{x,y,z},a,b,c}
```

I want to count the number of elements `c` in the last column that are greater than a certain number `d`. How can I do it?

Comment: `Total@UnitStep[data[[All, -1]] - d]`?  Of course, `Count` is much nicer to read, but also much slower. To have something nice to read and fast, check out [BoolEval](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/examples/id/31) (`BoolCount`)

Comment: The direct route:  `Count[ data, { __, c_ /; c > d}]`

Comment: Cannot understand what the structure of your list is.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ It contains a list and three numbers for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your long list is named `data`, one approach can be

```
Select[data, Last[#] > d &] // Length
```

where `d` should have a preset value.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{x, y, z}, 1, 2, 3}, {{a, y, z}, 2, 2, 1}, {{v, c, a}, 9, 7, 2}};
```

Using `Count`

```
Count[list, x_ /; Last[x] > 1]
```

2

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{x, y, z}, 1, 2, 3}, {{a, y, z}, 2, 2, 1}, {{v, c, a}, 9, 7, 2}};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequenceCount`:

```
SequenceCount[list, {s_ /; Last[s] > 1}]

(*2*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some variants:

```
list = {{{x, y, z}, 1, 2, 3}, {{a, y, z}, 2, 2, 1}, {{v, c, a}, 9, 7, 
    2}};
```

Counting:

```
True /. CountsBy[list, Last[#] > 1 &]
True /. GroupBy[list, Last@# > 1 &, Length]
Total[Last/*(# > 1 &)/*Boole /@ list]
```

All yield 2